# How Create Different Layouts For Single Wordpress Theme?

Tags: homepage

How can I create different layouts and style (Home with Sidebar, Home without Sidebar, Home Grid, ...) for a single Wordpress theme by choice of user in an Admin panel? Should I have different css and home pages? What I mean is like [this](http://demo.shapedtheme.com/kotha-pro-html/).

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but one way would be to use [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/). You can then select the template in the editor for each page.